# context of this in class and in setTimeout is JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, this, settimeout

I am new in JS also read all the answer regarding context of "this" with class and setTimeout() but i had one problem

I am not getting proper thought process/mental model of below code why "this" is changing

```
class Demo {
  getFilteredData (){
    console.log(this, 'inside'); // HERE THIS IS UNDEFINE
  };

  debounce(fn, d) {
    let timer;
    return function () {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      console.log(this); // HERE THIS OF CLASS ITSELF
      fn();
      timer = setTimeout(() => fn(), d);
    };
  }

  bettreFunction = this.debounce(this.getFilteredData, 450);
}

let a = new Demo()
a.bettreFunction()
```

OUTPUT

```
Demo {bettreFunction: ƒ}
undefined "inside"
undefined "inside"
```

I know I am calling fn() twice just to know both function call behavior
I also read MDN for function context and this keyword and also about setTimeout

so my question is
**Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called - MDN**
so here when I call fn() its this should be global or class's this or what ??

and also when I convert my getFilteredData() method to arrow function its taking this perfectly bcz - arrow function's this retains the value of the enclosing lexical context's this

so I can understand that when it is arrow function and I call fn() it's enclosing lexical context's this is of class (as I also printed it) so it will work fine

but what will be this when just calling fn() and fn is not arrow function as MDN says Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called.
so here why it is giving undefined what is thought process and mental model is it bcz of nested function or what should I think in my mind ?

please help I am new in JS and correct me if I am somewhere wrong, Thank you for your time and consideration

**Edit:**
I know .call(), .bind(), .apply() will work here as arrow also working just wanted to know what will happen in normal scenario

Answer (score -1):

bettreFunction = this.debounce(this.getFilteredData.bind(this), 450);

Update:

> > so here when I call fn() its this should be global or class's this or what ??

When you pass the function as a parameter you lose its context. In usual mode (not strict) it may be changed from undefined to global (e.g. Window) but read that:

> > Inside a function, the value of this depends on how the function is called

It also depends on whether "strict mode" is used. In strict mode the value of this is undefined if the context is lost.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#strict_mode

I'm not much skilled in js either so this is my opinion.

Comment: hey thanks for answering but my question was different I know bind, call, apply or arrow function will work here :)

Comment: Thank you :) , but I had one question as you said **When you pass the function as a parameter you lose its context** ok got it so when I call fn() this context is loss but it should pick then global object or window object may be ?? or what ?? why it is taking this as undefined ?

Comment: As the context is lost the value of this is undefined. In usual mode it changes to global: globalThis or Window. But as you pass class's method it is executed in strict mode. Try some outer function "getFilterData" for example to make sure that "this" changes to global depending on whether "strict mode" is enabled or not.

Comment: Let us say that when "this" has no context it points to the global object (globalThis in node.js or Window in a browser) but in strict mode remains undefined. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: oh so catch here for me is - inside class methods executed in strict mode 
I didn't knew that learned something new thank you , and yes correct me if I am wrong